# How to integrate AirPlay add in android Live wallpaper?

Tags: android, airpush

Recently Airpush provided their new sdk for playstore, but I am facing problems adding this in livewallpaper, in the previous sdk we used

```
Airpush airpush=new Airpush(getApplicationContext());
```

it worked, but for the new sdk we need to do this

```
AirPlay airPlay = new AirPlay(activity, null, true);
```

but the problem is when I try to do this in wallpaper service, it gives an error as it wants activity as parameter, what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their AirSDK universal SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is make a Settings activity and then Integrate the Standard SDK or you can also integrate the Universal SDK but it is not compliant with google play